# Use only Integers of a file with text

Tags: haskell

My function works ok. But I want to use this function with a file's text. The text file has a word before an integer list. How can I do this?

This is the function:

```
broke :: Integer -> Integer
broke n = pollard 1 2 n 2 2
```

The contents of the file is:

```
Word (11,12)
```

I want to apply the function `broke` to the first number.

Comment: I'm trying to understand why this question is tagged "monads" - What specifically are you asking about monads?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well this might be kind of a cheat, but the contents of that file is a valid Haskell expression so you could use `Read` to do it:

```
import System.IO (readFile)

data Word = Word (Integer,Integer)
    deriving (Read)

main = do
    contents <- readFile "path/to/file" -- or wherever your file is
    let Word (x,y) = read contents
    print $ broke x
```

The reason this works is that `deriving (Read)` automatically writes a parser for you, so you get the function `read :: String -> Word` for free.  So this technique is only going to work for files whose contents look like Haskell -- otherwise you will need to write your own [parser](https://two-wrongs.com/parser-combinators-parsing-for-haskell-beginners).

Comment: I wrote my parser for this, and worked it! Thanks, I understood the process, haskell makes it seem easy this kind of operation hahahahahaha